# Scope Not Updating When Using ng-click Within a Component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components

I have the issue that my scope is not updating when using ng-click within a component. The scope also does not update if I use $scope.$apply or $timeout so I am not sure what the issue is.

The idea is that when I click on my second button within my component (qdcPopover.html) that $scope.showGetData should be updated to true which will then update the div within my index.html.

Here is my code:

**index.html:**

```
<html lang="en" qva-bootstrap="false">
<head>
  <title>Data Prep</title>
  <script data-main="data-prep" src="/resources/assets/external/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
    <button id="qdpCreateApp" class="lui-button  lui-button--rounded">Create App</button>
    <qdp-popover></qdp-popover>
    <div>Hello {{showGetData}} + {{showAppCreate}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**qdpPopver.html (component)**

```
<div ng-show="showAppCreate" class="lui-popover" style="width: 400px;">
  <div class="lui-popover__header">
    <div class="lui-popover__title">{{qdpPopover.title}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lui-popover__body">
    {{qdpPopover.body}}
    <input id="{{qdpPopover.inputId}}" ng-show="qdpPopover.showInput" class="lui-input"/>
  </div>
  <div class="lui-popover__footer">
    <button class="lui-button  lui-popover__button" ng-click="showAppCreate = false">{{qdpPopover.button1}}</button>
    <button class="lui-button  lui-popover__button" ng-click="createApp()">{{qdpPopover.button2}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**data-prep-module.js**

```
// define the angular module with its controller
var app = angular.module('qlikDataPrepModule', []);

// define angular components
app.component('qdpPopover', {
    templateUrl: 'qdpPopover.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
})

var qdpAppNameInput = "qdpAppNameInput";
// Controller
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.qdpPopover = {
        title: "Create new App",
        body: "Name of my app:",
        button1: "Cancel",
        button2: "Create",
        showInput: true,
        inputId: qdpAppNameInput
    };
    $scope.showGetData = false;
    $scope.showAppCreate = false;

    // Function for app creation
    $scope.createApp = function () {
        $scope.showGetData = true;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
})
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `$apply` like this without parameter, and in your situation it's a bit useless as its use is to make actions done outside of angular go back into angular digest cycles, and in your case you're not outside of angular

Comment: Yup the first time I wrote this I did not use $scope.apply at all but then after searching for an answer to my problem I found only examples where this was used so I thought I would give it a try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a very simple example, i messed up a bit the function names and functionalities so that is probably not what you intended, but it's just an example.

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition) it seems that components scopes are always isolated, so even with the same controller, you actually have 2 different instances. There are examples with using `require` to communicate between components but couldn't get it to work.. (doc is a bit sparse there).

However something that works fine is by using a service. The service shares the data between all instances of you controller.

Hope that helps, good luck!

```js
// define the angular module with its controller
var app = angular.module('qlikDataPrepModule', []);

// define angular components
app.component('qdpPopover', {
    template: `<div ng-show="getShowAppCreate()" class="lui-popover" style="width: 400px;"><div>Hello {{getShowGetData()}} + {{getShowAppCreate()}}</div>
  <div class="lui-popover__header">
    <div class="lui-popover__title">{{qdpPopover.title}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="lui-popover__body">
    {{qdpPopover.body}}
    <input id="{{qdpPopover.inputId}}" ng-show="qdpPopover.showInput" class="lui-input"/>
  </div>
  <div class="lui-popover__footer">
    <button class="lui-button  lui-popover__button" ng-click="showAppCreate(false)">{{qdpPopover.button1}}</button>
    <button class="lui-button  lui-popover__button" ng-click="showGetData(true)">{{qdpPopover.button2}}</button>
  </div>
</div>`,
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
})

var qdpAppNameInput = "qdpAppNameInput";
// Controller
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http, dataService) {
    $scope.qdpPopover = {
        title: "Create new App",
        body: "Name of my app:",
        button1: "Cancel",
        button2: "Create",
        showInput: true,
        inputId: qdpAppNameInput
    };

    // Function for app creation
    $scope.showGetData = function (val) {
        dataService.showGetData = val;
    }
    $scope.getShowGetData = function () {
        return dataService.showGetData;
    }
    
    // Function for show popover
    $scope.showAppCreate = function (val) {
        dataService.showAppCreate = val;
    }
    $scope.getShowAppCreate = function () {
        return dataService.showAppCreate;
    }
})

app.factory('dataService', function(){
    var data = {};
    
    data.showGetData = false;
    data.showAppCreate = false;
    
    return data;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" qva-bootstrap="false">
<head>
  <title>Data Prep</title>
  <script data-main="data-prep" src="/resources/assets/external/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="qlikDataPrepModule">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
    <button id="qdpCreateApp" class="lui-button  lui-button--rounded" ng-click="showAppCreate(true)">Create App</button>
    <qdp-popover></qdp-popover>
    <div>Hello {{getShowGetData()}} + {{getShowAppCreate()}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) the $scope.$apply method needs a parameter to execute, try this:

```
$scope.createApp = function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.showGetData = true;
    });
}
```

Or maybe you are not in the right scope, is this all your code? You haven't even referenced angular.js

Comment: I have tried this before as well and just tried it again but it is still not working